# Unable to use "load data infile" function in mysql in macbook M1

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

When I tried following command `show variables like 'secure_file_priv'` it returns null, what to do?

I've added `my.cnf` in the location `/usr/local/mysql/`
and added the following text in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld] 
secure-file-priv=""
```

After that I ticked the configuration tab in mysql in system setting and added the location of `my.cnf` in it. After that I restarted the server, the server ain't restarting. However when I tried to start the server after unticking the configuration tab it restarted.

Or (I did the following thing which is mentioned in following the video, check out [the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fG8N2PhoACk&list=LL&index=4&t=174s)).

What to do?